# Avoid changing JS variable value when true value is previously set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that checks a textbox value and return either true or false regarding it value.

I have several textboxes to check:

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" class="tocheck" runat="server />
<asp:textbox id="txt2" class="tocheck" runat="server />
<asp:textbox id="txt3" class="tocheck" runat="server />
```

and when I press the submit button (Linkbutton1) I check all their values:

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each($('.tocheck'), function (i, v) {
        error =  check($(v).val(), $(this));
    });
    return error;
});
```

If one of the calls return true the overall validation must be considered failed and the `true` value must be kept.

So what I want is prevent the error variable to be set to `false` when it's already previously set to `true`.

Is there any **operator** or **function** that controls this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each($('.tocheck'), function (i, v) {
        if (!error) {
            error =  check($(v).val(), $(this));
        }
    });
    return error;
});
```

You can also return `false` in the function to break the each. More information in the documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Just couple of notes: 1) `$.each($(".tocheck"), ...)` can be replaced with `$(".tocheck").each(...)`. 2) `size()` is deprecated, use `length`. 3) `.tocheck` is a text field, not a checkbox.

Comment: yes i just saw that my code with filter was bad, i just removed it.

Comment: @Magnus I can't break the each because I do logical code into check function.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$("#LinkButton1").click(function() {
    return $(".tocheck").filter(function() {
        return check(this.value, this);
    }).length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each($('.tocheck'), function (i, v) {
        error =  check($(v).val(), $(this));
        if(error)
            return error;
    });
    return error;
});
```